# Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false after clicking back button

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am currently learning ionic using the v1 framework.

and I am encountering this warning everytime I tap the back button in my header or whenever I change screens:

`Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.`

when change screen, this warning pops up in the console, and I need to double-tap in order to make the button on the current screen work..

How can I remove this warning?